# Bash string comparing with text

Tags: string, bash, syntax, compare, variable-assignment

I want to make a bash script which give me ready for use YAML to create docker instance.
I have a skeleton file where I take a strings and put it to $customer file line by line. All strings should be transferred as is, but PASS, ADMIN, NAME are needed to be replaced, but my IF never match. I have a simple txt where few strings with inly one char in string (like 1,2,3,4,5,6,q,w,e,r,t) which never replaced by my script. I try to change IF few different ways but nothing works for me.
What and how I should change it?

```
#!/bin/bash
#inputs
read -p 'Input customer name: ' customer
read -p 'Input admin name: ' admin
read -p 'Input admin password: ' pass
mkdir ~/$customer ;  touch ~/$customer/$customer.yaml
#here we are taking scelet for YAML config
input="/home/x/1.txt"
#and read it line by line
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo $line
#replacing lines in sceleton to our inputs
        if [[ $line == "q" ]]; then
                line = $customer
        elif [[ $line == "r" ]] ; then
                line = $admin
        elif [[ $line == "4" ]]; then
                line = $pass
        else
#write lines to new yaml
        echo "$line" >> ~/$customer/$customer.yaml
fi
done < $input
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made the

Comment: You did not post the exact content of your input file, but in `line` really contains a single _q_  only, `[[ $line == "q" ]]` will match. I would verify the content of `line` not with `echo` (which can be misleading), but with `xxd <<<$line`.

Answer (score 0):

More experienced colleague help me. Problem was that I should first work with IF/ELIF/ELSE, close IF with FI and after write string to file.

```js
#!/bin/bash
#inputs
read -p 'Input customer name: ' customer
read -p 'Input admin name: ' admin
read -p 'Input admin password: ' pass
#read -p 'Retype admin pass: ' passw
#pass is confirmed?
        #if [[ $pass == $passw ]]; then
        mkdir ~/$customer ;  touch ~/$customer/$customer.yaml
#here we are taking scelet for YAML config
        input="/home/x/1.txt"
#and read it line by line
        while IFS= read -r line
        do
#replacing lines in sceleton to our inputs
        if [[ "$line" =~ "q" ]]; then
                line=$customer
        elif [[ "$line" =~ "r" ]] ; then
                line=$admin
        elif [[ "$line" =~ "4" ]]; then
                line=$pass
        fi
#write lines to new yaml
        echo "$line" >> ~/$customer/$customer.yaml
        done < $input
echo "Ta-Da!!!"
```